# GitLab CI rules:if match condition which fails in Bash

Tags: bash, gitlab-ci

In `.gitlab-ci.yml` we do have a rule matching a value with regex match. Why is `rule-regex` job running with `if: $EMPTY_VAR =~ "some-value"` when Bash tells this condition is false?

If I set `EMPTY_VAR: 'x'` no job runs.

```yaml
variables:
  EMPTY_VAR: ''

default:
  image: container-registry.ubs.net/alpine:3.12.3

# Runs against expectation and prints 'expected false'
rule-regex:
  rules:
    - if: $EMPTY_VAR =~ "some-value"
  script:
    - echo "Job has run with EMPTY_VAR='${EMPTY_VAR}'"
    - |
      if [[ $EMPTY_VAR =~ "some-value" ]]; then
        echo "expected true"
      else
        echo "expected false"
      fi

# Does not run as expected
rule-equal:
  rules:
    - if: $EMPTY_VAR == "some-value"
  script:
    - echo "Job has run with EMPTY_VAR='${EMPTY_VAR}'"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
- if: $EMPTY_VAR =~ /^some-value.*/
```

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#compare-a-variable-to-a-regex-pattern